# Overiding return value to a method for all calls from unit/ integration test class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I want to write test for method of a class that is tightly coupled with other classes. The constructor for method's class is as follows:

```
public BTPhysicalAccount(List<IVirtualAccount> virtualAccounts, BTMarketInfo marketInfo, double initialVABalance)
```

I do not want to fake BTMarket so I will instantiate it as well, constructor of this class is:

```
public BTMarketInfo(HistoricDbData historicDbData, double minLotSize)
```

I want to do same for HistoricDbData class so it's constructor is:

```
public HistoricDbData(ILogger logger)
        {
            HistoricDataSet historicDataSet = new HistoricDataSet(currency,new DateTime(2000, 06, 01), new DateTime(2000, 06, 10), logger);
        }
```

Now the problem arises in this constructor, when it tries to instantiate HistoricDataSet. Code for it's constructor is as follows:

```
    public HistoricDataSet(Currency currency, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, ILogger logger)
            {


   IHistoricPricesRepository historicRepository = new HistoricPriceRepository(new BackTestingAgentModelDBEntities2());
            List<HistoricDataPoint> _dataSet = historicRepository.GetHistoricDataPoints(currency, startDateTime, endDateTime);
        }
```

HistoricRepository here is linked to database and I want to mock `GetHistoricDataPoints` method and return a fake list of data points.
From test class I have access to constructors of BTMarketInfo and BTPhysicalAccount only. How can I set this `GetHistoricDataPoints` method to return fake list of data points. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Edit: I tried to mock it like:

```
var shamRespository = Substitute.For<IHistoricPricesRepository>();
            shamRespository.GetHistoricDataPoints(Arg.Any<Currency>(), Arg.Any<DateTime>(), Arg.Any<DateTime>()).Returns(PopulateDataPoints());
```

However, it did not work, the obvious reason is that `shamRepository` is never passed in any constructor method.

Comment: you are instantiating an instance of `HistoricPriceRepository` with that method which make it difficult to test. `IHistoricPricesRepository` should also be a dependency of that class so that it can be mocked/faked when needed.

Comment: Yes, but now It is not and I am not supposed to refactor the code. So is there any other way to mock or fake it?

Comment: Well yes there are two main ways: Typeisolators (e.g. Microsoft Fakes or typemock) or Local Db.